# Where are the tags in the Users list coming from?

Tags: support, tags, users

When browsing the [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week) list today I have noticed a strange tag appearing under my name:

[image]

and when I click on the [access-rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-rights) tag there is no such and pretty sure never answered questions in such area:

[image]

So how is the list of 3 tags shown there calculated and what's with the `access-rights` tag in my case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[C#: access right due to inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722695/c-access-right-due-to-inheritance)

The reason you could not find that question was you are on the `featured` tab, which is hidden because there are no bountied questions with that tag. Click `active` to the right of *Tagged Questions* to see the questions with the [access-rights](/questions/tagged/access-rights) tag.

> So how is the list of 3 tags shown there calculated and what's with the access-rights tag in my case?

At this point in time, the `week` subtab is the default for the Users ranking, so only posts in the last week are taken into account.

Comment: thanks for clearing my confusion. Indeed I have to learn how to use this site.